# Is religion possible in a society where backwards time-travel exists?

Tags: time-travel, religion

Assuming a society where backwards time-travel is possible and a fixed-time universe (you can't change anything that happened in the past), would our modern concept of religion continue to exist? My thinking is that at least Judaism and Christianity would have problems since:

- Traveling 10000 years ago would show the world still existed, negating the Torah
- Traveling to the year of the supposed crucifixion would show Jesus didn't perform anything supernatural

Islam might have problems as well, since it's based on the two Abrahamic religions. My thinking is that new religions will arise instead, which are independant on past events.

Comment: While I don't necessarily support the Torah or Bible (or any specific religious work) I would say that these books can and probably will be interpreted by the believers of their religions to mean different things. Anyway, why not travel back in time to the beginning of everything to see if there was some sort of divine creator?

Comment: You make the assumption (prior to time travel that everything is a hoax).  If you already believe that...what is the point?  Wouldn't the impact of such travel be dictated by what you actually find?  Can everyone travel back in time?

Comment: I am having trouble identifying what the actual question is here, can you clarify?  It seems you have posited an idea and want us to validate your thinking?

Comment: @James the question is whether a world where time-travel is possible, but otherwise the physics is the same could support religion as we know it. Time-travel is a common concept in science fiction, but I haven't seen any books treating the question of the effect on religion.

Comment: So would a more concise version of your question read:  *If traveling back in time (with all your limitations mentioned) revealed that religions x, y, and z never demonstrated supernatural powers/happenings/beings, what would be the impact to the modern day religions?*

Comment: There's always the God of the Gaps, even if you plug a bunch of gaps. We already know for certain that the world existed 10000 years ago, so time travel wouldn't change much. I think you might be focusing too much on "it would disprove X religion" and not enough on "it would prove X religion is totally different than it was before." For example, the bible has been heavily edited and re-translated. An indisputably authentic collection of writings which eventually became the bible could be disruptive.

Comment: Can you define "modern concept religion" here?  I have a feeling you will have the effect of invalidating a large number of religions, but I think you may open up the doors for a whole entire class of new religions, assuming we define religion with a very open definition.  And are we including just the tiny effects of being able to go disprove claims, or are we taking about the **gargantuan** effects of being able to go through time, which will affect literally everything in the entire world.

Comment: Fantastic idea for a story, by the way. I'm surprised no one has touched this yet.

Comment: Religion has *already* had to deal with interpreting its texts in light of later science.  AFAIK, for example, most Jews and Christians *don't* believe the earth is <6000 years old.

Comment: @BrettFromLA http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0314226/ is kind of relevant to the idea

Comment: @MonicaCellio But most Jews and Christians do believe Moses was 600+ years old.

Comment: Moses?  The text says he lived to 120.

Comment: @BrettFromLA # of years doesn't seem relevant as your claim that most believe he lived a long time isn't correct either.  I would put the ages of the early biblical figures in the same category as the age of the world...

Comment: @MonicaCellio Well one of those guys lived over 600 years. Google says Noah lived 950 years. And his son, Shem, lived 600 years.

Comment: @WilliamKappler "We already know for certain that the world existed 10000 years ago"  I'd really love to see what'd happen if *this* worldview was disrupted.  I mean, it's so easy to wonder what would happen if someone else's world view was wrong, much harder your own.

Comment: If backwards time travel is possible, but you can't change the past, then you have a system functionally indistinguishable from a camera that can look back through time.  Have a look at [*Legion*, by Brandon Sanderson,](http://www.amazon.com/Legion-Brandon-Sanderson-ebook/dp/B0099D4KEG/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1440018528&sr=1-3) for a very interesting look at such a camera, including what its effects would be on privacy, secrecy, and religion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a lot of evidence that says that early Jesus followers didn't believe Jesus was the literal son of God ('son of God' was more of a title, for instance it was used to refer to Caesar), and didn't believe he rose from the dead (a lot of early texts don't talk about his death, since it was so shameful). Instead, the early communities focused on Jesus's message about how the world was wrong, but a better one was on the horizon, and we could all do our part to bring it about.

Thus, I would say that although a lot of religion would be different, it would not be altogether missing. People believe in God not because *people* tell them to, but because *God* tells them to; if you're assuming that God doesn't exist, then no amount of backwards time travel is ever going to help us learn more about him.

That said, I would assume religion would be a lot less dogmatic (not sure if that's the right word), and a lot more spiritual. Meditation works, as does a lifestyle free from worldly pleasures. These things have demonstrable effects, and some people attribute them to the divine; on the other hand, there's no real evidence to support hating gay people, so that probably won't make the cut.

The only other option I can think of is that backwards time travel isn't something everyone will do. Poor people won't have the ability to, and people firmly fixed to their beliefs may be too afraid to be proven wrong to try it. So, in that case, a lot of modern religion will persist.

EDIT: Come to think of it, I would love it if this happened, and I think a lot of intelligent religious people would too. People who don't take the Bible literally really want to know what *actually* happened; to be able to hear Jesus speak would be like hearing Socrates speak, an absolutely priceless experience that could help fill in the gaps of history, and end the debates once and for all. With the ability to hear the prophets and founders of every religion, I think believers would become closer to one another, as they no longer would have to fight over what they think is right.

Comment: In regard to your edit: I think people would still argue about what they think is right, since everyone interprets messages differently and to different extremes.

Comment: @Frostfyre I agree, I was just thinking there would be *less* arguments. For instance, we'd know which parts of the New Testament were actually from Jesus, and which parts were made up later.

Comment: We'd also know what material excluded from the Bible by the [first Council of Nicaea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Council_of_Nicaea) should actually have been included.

Comment: @Frostfyre Sure, but I'd think after backwards time travel, we'd have to write a whole new Bible.

Comment: Why the downvote? I appreciate that it puts my rep at a nice round number, but I'd like to improve my answer if I can.

Comment: Jesus was made "son of God" during the [First Council of Nicaea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Council_of_Nicaea). It was a political decision, the selection of gospels in the canon was aligned to this decision.

Comment: Not only is your rep a round number, but it also counts!

Answer (score 8):

Yes it could.

Your question assumes that all religions depend on false historical claims. Religions could definitely exist which either do not depend on historical claims, or else depend on historical claims which are true.

**No Historical Claims**

As other answers have noted, many religions (or varieties of religions) do not depend on historical claims. This is especially true in eastern religions which can tend more towards being philosophies of life than dogmatic religions like Judaism. Of course, many believers in relatively dogmatic religions modify their beliefs to fit facts, often by reinterpreting seemingly historical passages as being "only" stories for communicating a certain lesson.

In addition to "philosophy" oriented beliefs, animistic beliefs also do not depend on historical claims. Nobody can use any machine to demonstrate that the earth (or trees) has no soul.

**No *False* Historical Claims**

On the other hand, why not suppose that some religions are based on *true* events which are (or at least appear to be) supernatural. Maybe the earth is only 10,000 years old. Maybe The Resurrection is genuine. We may have good reason to believe that this isn't the case, but then we also have good reason to believe that time travel to the past is impossible.

If some historical miracles appear to be genuine, then time-traveling witnesses would tend to strengthen the status of the religions associated with those miracles. Religions would begin to shift to using the same set of miracles, only with different interpretations. This happens even without modern confirmation of miracles: both Christianity and Islam assert that Jesus performed miracles, they just have different opinions on precisely *what* miracles, and set different levels of importance on Jesus himself.

**Edit because I thought of some comparable fiction:**

It's also possible that some highly-important coordinates might be difficult or impossible to access through a *handwave* timeline protection law of physics. Connie Willis' *Doomsday Book* (and other books in the Oxford Time Travel series) employs something like this to prevent time traveling historians from  messing up the past. Since the early stages of a major world religion might be incredibly sensitive to tampering or accidents, they might just be impossible to access.

Comment: Related to "no *false* claims", there's also the possibility that totally natural events (such as a localized rise in sea level) could have been *passed down* as supernatural ("the world got flooded") without actually being so.  Also, I remember a story where so many people looked back in time to see the crucifixion that their viewing portals interfered with each other and no one could see the critical moment.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean with "modern conception of religion." For example different groups of Christians have widely divergent interpretations of what religion means. Similar diversity exists inside most religions. There isn't really a single correct way to be religious. Or to see religion.

Generally, only some religious conservatives and fundamentalists see using scripture as a science textbook to be meaningful. Most religious people would be just fine, and are just fine, in thinking that a book that was not intended to teach science has gaps and even inaccuracies when it comes to science.

And even the fundamentalists would be just fine. They already ignore any scientific evidence contrary to their believes. Having time machines add some extra data to ignore would not change anything. Fundamentalists do not really believe religion is about studying science either, the only difference is that they for theological reasons draw the line between the two at a different place. Or in other words assume the gaps and inaccuracies are at a different place. This works since all human information whether it is read from a sacred book or gained by using a time machine has gaps and inaccuracies.

As for going and observing Jesus and other religious figures... It would be interesting and lots of people would have to change their romanticized or superstitious views about some people, but it is fundamentally not really that important. For example, the important thing about Jesus is not actually performing miracles, being resurrected, or being the son of God, even though those are very important to some people and entire denominations. The important thing was what he taught.

And even there... It is fairly obvious that what Jesus taught and what modern Christianity teaches are quite different in fairly important ways. Despite what people may wish even religious teachings supported by a sacred text are context sensitive. That is the way it is supposed to be, really. So even finding large contradictions with what we believe would have limited impact long term.

In short term lots of religious people have fairly silly views of their own religion and would be greatly upset. Similarly lots of strictly non-religious people have somehow just accepted that religion must be silly and superstitious since so many loudly religious people think so. They would be greatly confused and even upset by the failure of religion to fold up and die after being proven wrong.

So no, it wouldn't change much. Religion is about your beliefs, values, and identity, who you are, not about the stories and the supernatural, what happened millennia ago.

Comment: My experience is that a lot of religions share beliefs and values (be nice to people, help those in need, have moments of silence and gratitude daily), but religious people identify strongly with only a single religion - they're Christian not Jewish, or Jewish not Mulsim, or.... So I don't think it's true that religion is about your beliefs and values.

Comment: @BrettFromLA You are right that they identify strongly with a specific religious group. I probably should have mentioned that in the answer. The reason I didn't was that the time machine has no real impact with your group identity. Thanks for pointing out the omission, I'll probably edit it in.

Answer (score 1):

Religion doesn't only make impossible claims about things far before our own lifespan, or far in the future.

You can't time-travel to the afterlife, for instance... Or anywhere outside of physical space (and thusly, any location outside of the creation of physical spacetime). So it is likely that religions would still exist on these topics.

That's really the problem with most religious claims. Once we discover something with absolute scientific certainty, the goalposts are moved.

Comment: " Once we discover something with absolute scientific certainty..." we know that we're no longer doing science?  Consider every scientific truth you know, then consider which *could* be disproved by time travel.  Then consider how that could impact your world view.

Comment: @NPSF3000 You seem to have disconnected your railcar from my train of thought; Zealots used to claim that God was responsible for everything. Science found out that for a great many of these things, that's simply not true. God didn't give us Smallpox 'because we're sinners'. We know this because we've cured Smallpox and completely eradicated it from our species. If our "sinful nature" caused Smallpox, we would not have been able to do that. But of course, "the goalposts are moved", meaning God is everywhere else, until science disproves it. Can time travel prove that 'sin causes Smallpox'? No.

Comment: "God didn't give us Smallpox 'because we're sinners'. We know this because we've cured Smallpox and completely eradicated it from our species."  That's one *viewpoint* but not necessarily true.  One could just as easily argue that it's only because of God/Gods that we allowed/enabled/permitted to cure smallpox.  Or worse, we did it against Gods will and have a worse punishment awaiting us.  Science does not and cannot give us any 'truth' in these matters, it can only observe the world and test hypothesis.

Comment: And yet, has anyone ever SEEN a God? Any God? Any single God, ever? Can I just travel down to the corner store and see a God there? One could just as easily argue that it's only because of a sentient invisible pink teapot that we allowed/enabled/permitted to cure smallpox. One would be no more or less wrong than anyone arguing in favor of gods. And neither of them would pass scientific scrutiny.

Comment: Sure people have, and their experiences have been documented.  Scientific scrutiny does not give one truth, it simply tells you what (according to peer review, and the limits of science) what is the best story to believe.  The opponents of Ignaz Semmelweis knew that he was scientifically and mentally wrong, imagine their horror if they could travel to the future and see how many people died due to their ignorance?

Comment: You say "their experiences have been documented," but how reliable is the source? Does the controlling embassy have any vested interest in whether or not people believe it as fact (ie, do they collect money from believers)? The experiences have been documented of people who have met Superman. Should I accept those documents at face value? Also, if you're referencing the Christian bible, I should remind you: John 1:18 AND John 4:12-"No one has ever seen God."

Comment: So you have a current belief that no-one has seen god (for arugments sake).  You use unreliability of sources etc as the basis of your belief.  With this new time travel device, you go back in time and witness god in person.  How does this impact your beliefs?

Comment: I don't have a belief. Babies are born *agnostic-atheist*, and remain that way unless they are indoctrinated by snake-oil salesmen. With this new time-travel device, I go back and witness any number of things; delusional men tripping on mushrooms and making things up, snide priests inventing stories to control the masses, centuries worth of mass-murderers using religion to validate their slaughter... In the odd event that I DO witness an alien intelligence genetically engineering humankind, then **I would update my interpretation of reality** to include that fact.

Comment: Which is merely how intelligent scientific people differ from gullible religious people. Science **accepts new information** and **documents the changes**. Religious people would **smash the time travel device** and **call it a devil-machine**.

Comment: If "Science accepts new information and documents the changes" how can you possibly explain this statement:  "Once we discover something with absolute scientific certainty...".  How can you on one hand claim to have absolute certainty, and on the other hand accept that new information could change your reality?  For example you claim "Religious people would smash the time travel device and call it a devil-machine." I'm religious, and I would not smash a time machine because it's a 'devil machine'.  Ignaz Semmelweis saw personally how well 'scientists' can accept new information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24935/discussion-between-ayelis-and-npsf3000).

Comment: Also FWIW: "Scientific certainty" is different from "Colloquial certainty". In much the same way "Scientific theory" is different from "Colloquial theory". ([Continued in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24935/discussion-between-ayelis-and-npsf3000))

Answer (score 1):

New holy wars could be started over this: followers of one religion trying to disprove other religions, while simultaneously trying to suppress examination of the miracles claimed within their own religion.

(That's not really an answer to your question, just a religious ramification of time-travel-related fact-checking.)